# Como submeter um formulario com select sem botão submit?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Boa noite, como eu faço para submeter um formulário com select sem o botão submit? Por exemplo, to criando um filtro que quando seleciona o option ele automaticamente submete o formulario sem ter o botão submit.

Meu formulário tá assim:

```
<form class="form-inline left" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="listar">Listar por</label>
                <select id="filtro" name="filtro" class="form-control">
                    <option value="professor">Professor</option>
                    <option value="assunto">Assunto</option> 
                </select>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Vinicius, reparei que nunca marcaste como aceite uma resposta às tuas pergunta. É aconselhável fazê-lo, quem te ajuda recebe pontos por ter dado a resposta que melhor solucionou o teu problema. Podes ler mais sobre isso no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/129

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes fazer isso diretamente no select com `onchange="this.form.submit()"`:

```
<select id="filtro" name="filtro" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

Dessa maneira quando o evento `change` for criado ele envia o formulário diretamente.

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/kgfcetud/

Outra maneira é usar um ausculador de evento assim:

```
document.getElementById('filtro').addEventListener('change', function() {
    this.form.submit();
});
```

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/rdhcp58d/

Comment: Obrigado, era isso mesmo que eu queria, mas não fica um pouco obstrusivo não? Será que teria outra solução?

Comment: @ViniciusAquino isso é a maneira ao estilo React, mas juntei outra versão agora. A primeira tem a vantagem de deixar o codigo relacionado já no elemento, uma vez que é pouco código e só diz respeito a ele próprio.

Comment: @Sergio sem o submit cada vez que for selecionado alguma opção a opção será enviada, em caso de clicar na opção errada também correto ?
Existe outra forma de prevenir isso sem o submit?

Comment: @MagicHat cada vez que o valor mudar, mas não somente com `click` de abrir.

Comment: Muito obrigado!